# GWT do not detects my browser corectly

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

When I run my APP under IE9 it fails with a lot of JS errors and I receive attached message even that I run my APP with IE9. This confuses my code, because elements in js do not accept addEventListener under IE6. 
This is my GWT.xml file

```
       <module rename-to="MyModuleName">
       <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
   <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.xml.XML"/>
   <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
       <inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.charts.Charts"/>      
      <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie9"/>
      <entry-point class="com.test.MyModuleName"/>
    </module>
```

[image]
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Try again after removing `<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie9"/>` line from gwt.xml. Compile the project for all possible permutations.

Comment: I've tried again without this line and navigator detects that my browser language is ie6

Comment: sometime if goes to compatibility mode, check it again using F12. It happened with me between IE8 and IE7. Have you GWT compiled the project again?

Comment: No, it is not on compatibility view. Yes, project is compile successfully again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IE8+ will use the ie6 permutation if they switch to quirks mode. Make you you have a doctype that triggers standards mode (simplest is `<!doctype HTML>`) and/or include a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`

Comment: I receive the same message again, even that I set meta tag in UIGenerator

Comment: What is UIGenerator? You should put those in your HTML host page. Check in the IE Developer Tools (F12) that IE doesn't run in quirks mode (IE 5.5). It should ideally use a Document Mode equivalent to the IE version.